# Android actionBar Home enabled, set click listener

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, onclicklistener

For some reason, I cannot access my home icon for my application because it is not defined by an id but defined in the manifest. I want to be able to set an onclick listener for this action bar icon.
In this method, I set the icon but I do not know how to set an onclick listener for this because it isn't defined by an ID

```
public void actionBarSetUp() {
    // get action bar
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    // Enabling Up / Back navigation
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    // set the icon
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.app_logo_high_res);

}
```

Comment: `android.R.id.home` is the ID for the `View`.

Comment: android.R.id.home doesn't exist in my resources

Comment: `android.R.id.home` is defined in System resources. you need to import `android.R` class...

Comment: clean build issue, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your activity should extends ActionBarActivity as such you probably have this override available :-

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish(); // Or what ever action you want here.
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```